# SQL query to select first value from a column having repeated number

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to retrieve all the fist value of the repeating value in a column.
My table is like below

```
ID   FirstName   LastName   sequence
1      John        Doe       1
2      Bugs        Bunny     1
3      hari        Joh       2
4      Ram        Johns      2
5      Ramaaa     Sam        3
```

I want the query which will return me the value `john,hari,Ramaaa` from FirstName

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` Clause with `MIN()` function to get the top most firstname and lastname

```
SELECT 
        MIN(ID) ID,
        MIN(FirstName) FirstName,
        MIN(LastName) LastName,   
        sequence 
FROM table 
GROUP BY sequence
```

You could also use *sub-query* approach

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ID IN (
     SELECT MIN(ID) FROM table
     GROUP BY sequence
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, seq
FROM 
( SELECT id, firstname, lastname, seq,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq ORDER BY seq) RANK 
FROM YOUR_TABLE ) 
WHERE RANK = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID IN ( SELECT MIN(id) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY seq )
```